# In Shell script how can i loop through a variable containing other variables

Tags: shell, loops

I need to create a loop. The loop variable contains other variables. This is what i have tried

```
parentClients="name1 name2"
effectedClients="value1 value2"
otherClients="something1 something2 something3"
client_types="$parentClients $effectedClients $otherClients"
do
   echo $client
#this should print "parentClients" in 1st iteration and "effectedClients" in second and so on.
   for ct in $client
      do
        echo $ct
#this should print name1 name2 nd so on.
      done
      echo "done with one set"
done
```

The problem with this code is that its resolving all the values and assigning to the variable client_types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using bash

With bash, we can use arrays and indirection:

```
parentClients=(name1 name2)
effectedClients=(value1 value2)
otherClients=(something1 something2 something3)
client_types=(parentClients effectedClients otherClients)
for client in "${client_types[@]}"
do
   echo "client=$client"
   c=$client[@]
   for ct in "${!c}"
   do
      echo "  ct=$ct"
   done
   echo "done with one set"
done
```

This produces the output:

```
client=parentClients
  ct=name1
  ct=name2
done with one set
client=effectedClients
  ct=value1
  ct=value2
done with one set
client=otherClients
  ct=something1
  ct=something2
  ct=something3
done with one set
```

The statement `parentClients=(name1 name2)` creates an array named `parentClients` with values `name1` and `name2`.  The expression `${!c}` uses indirection to access the array whose name is given by `c`.

#### Using POSIX shell

With a POSIX shell, we must use variables instead of arrays and, in place of indirection, we use `eval`:

```
parentClients="name1 name2"
effectedClients="value1 value2"
otherClients="something1 something2 something3"
client_types="parentClients effectedClients otherClients"
for client in $client_types
do
   echo "client=$client"
   eval "client_list=\$$client" # Potentially dangerous step
   for ct in $client_list
   do
      echo "  ct=$ct"
   done
   echo "done with one set"
done
```

Because `eval` requires some trust in the source of the data, it should be used with caution.

This produces the output:

```
client=parentClients
  ct=name1
  ct=name2
done with one set
client=effectedClients
  ct=value1
  ct=value2
done with one set
client=otherClients
  ct=something1
  ct=something2
  ct=something3
done with one set
```